# Does Jose4J handle an HTTP Status 307 (temporarily redirect)

Tags: jose4j, http-status-code-307

I was wondering whether Jose4J handles the redirect http status codes (e.g. 307) when retrieving the JWKS from the OpenID Connect Endpoint.

I myself now do the retrieval and pass on the JWKS to Jose4J so called out of band. Now when i switched network i got a lot of 307's and wonder if it's wise to let Jose4J do the JWKS retrieval when it supports 307 and the other redirect statusses

```
        HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
        HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
        HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER
```

Thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will follow redirects when making requests to a JWKS endpoint. `org.jose4j.keys.resolvers.HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver` uses `org.jose4j.jwk.HttpsJwks` that by default uses `org.jose4j.http.Get` which in turn uses java's HttpsURLConnection that will follow redirects unless the behaviour has been changed at the class level:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects-boolean-